# Css Properties and TextStyle Types

Tags: typescript, react-native

I have a textStyle which is a type of TextStyle (it comes from react-native types) or React.CSSProperties. I want to pass this type to style attribute for html span element. style attribute accepts type of React.CSSProperties. My interface and span element is:

```
export interface IBaseTextStyleType {
    textStyle:  React.CSSProperties | TextStyle
}

<span style={style.textStyle}>
    {this.props.children || this.props.text}
</span>
```

I got this error in style of span:

```
Type 'CSSProperties | TextStyle' is not assignable to type 'CSSProperties'.
  Type 'TextStyle' is not assignable to type 'CSSProperties'.
    Types of property 'aspectRatio' are incompatible.
      Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'AspectRatio'.
```

How can I rid of this error ?

Comment: `TextStyle` makes sense on React Native's `Text` component, and not on `span` which takes `CSSProperties` type. What is goal here?

Comment: My goals is: gathering common areas on both sides(web and native). Web has specific style props and rn has specific style props too. But there is common styles. Developer could select React.CSSProperties or TextStyle.

Comment: I think a better design would be to create a component something like this `(props: IBaseTextStyleType) => isWeb ? <span style={props.textStyle as CSSProperties}>{...}</span> : <Text style={props.textStyle as TextStyle}>{...}</Text>`

Comment: Thats would be great but. I have just created all components for both.

Comment: As far as I know `<span>` wouldn't work in a react native project, would it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You try to define type of `style.textStyle` like this:

```
<span style={style.textStyle as React.CSSProperties}>
    {this.props.children || this.props.text}
</span>
```