# Import types two different project

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native

I have a project which includes two sub projects. Web for web(react), native for RN. I have common styles for components, then I created interfaces. Developer could write web or native style codes. The following interface has buttonStyle. buttonStyle React.CSSProperties type for Web, ViewStyle type for RN. My issue is I cannot import these interface from common interface. I have to import these interfaces two project. It causes code duplicate. How can I import these interfaces from common file.

[image: Project structure]

[image: common interface for button]

Comment: I think you've already asked exactly the same question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65932634/css-properties-and-textstyle-types

Comment: No, it is not the same. I solved that issue with //@ts-ignore for now.

Comment: cool. It sounded the same. BTW, `ts-ignore` forfeits the whole purpose of using Typescript.

Comment: If you use "and" instead of "or" you can require only properties which are acceptable to both the web and native versions.  `buttonStyle: React.CSSProperties & ViewStyle`.  Is that acceptable, or do you need to use any properties/value that are only supported in `ViewStyle` or only in `React.CSSProperties`?

Answer (score 0):

In order to have a common style that applied to both the web and the native versions you need to make sure that it passes the type checks for both types.  What you have now requires that `buttonStyle` is assignable to `React.CSSProperties` ***or*** `ViewStyle`.  You need to require that it is assignable to ***both*** in order to use that style on a `View` and a `button`.  Just switch your `|` (which is a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#union-types)) to `&` (which is an [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#intersection-types)).

```
export interface IButtonStyle extends INavigationStyle {
    buttonStyle: React.CSSProperties & ViewStyle;
}
```